# how to create a list view when a button is pressed using fragment

Tags: android, list, listview, android-fragments, fragment

in my application there is a navigation drawer. when any item is clicked in the drawer a text view is displayed. i do this using fragments. it works fine till this point.
now i want to show a list when second item is clicked in the navigation drawer. but it keeps crashing the  app. the list is custom with a custom adapter and is created using list fragment.

**in MainActivity.java**

```
private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener
{
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
    {
        selectItem(position);
```

**selectItem method**

```
private void selectItem(int position)
{
    int pos = position;
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (pos) {
    case 0: 
        fragment = new FragmentSell();
        break;

    case 1: 
        fragment = new FragmentBuy();
        break;
    }
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();
```

**adapter**

```
public class FragmentBuyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ItemBuy> {

private ArrayList<ItemBuy> objects;
public ArrayAdapter<Integer> adapter_weight;
public String weight;
public Context context;

public FragmentBuyAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
        ArrayList<ItemBuy> objects) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
    this.objects = objects;
    this.context = context;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View v = convertView;

    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_buy_list_item, null);
    }

    ItemBuy i = objects.get(position);

    if (i != null) {

        TextView name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_shop_name);
        TextView desc = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_shop_description);

            if (name != null) {
                name.setText(i.getName());
            }
            if (desc != null) {
                desc.setText(i.getDesc());
            }
        }

        return v;
    }
}
```

logcat-

```
10-15 11:37:05.860: W/dalvikvm(973): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception group=0xb4aebb90)
10-15 11:37:05.890: E/AndroidRuntime(973): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-15 11:37:05.890: E/AndroidRuntime(973): Process: com.coach.zudash, PID: 973
10-15 11:37:05.890: E/AndroidRuntime(973): java.lang.RuntimeException: Content has view with id attribute 'android.R.id.list' that is not a ListView class
10-15 11:37:05.890: E/AndroidRuntime(973):  at android.app.ListFragment.ensureList(ListFragment.java:402)
10-15 11:37:05.890: E/AndroidRuntime(973):  at android.app.ListFragment.onViewCreated(ListFragment.java:203)
10-15 11:37:05.890: E/AndroidRuntime(973):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:904)
10-15 11:37:05.890: E/AndroidRuntime(973):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
10-15 11:37:05.890: E/AndroidRuntime(973):  at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:684)
10-15 11:37:05.890: E/AndroidRuntime(973):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1447)
10-15 11:37:05.890: E/AndroidRuntime(973):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:443)
10-15 11:37:05.890: E/AndroidRuntime(973):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
10-15 11:37:05.890: E/AndroidRuntime(973):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
10-15 11:37:05.890: E/AndroidRuntime(973):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-15 11:37:05.890: E/AndroidRuntime(973):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
10-15 11:37:05.890: E/AndroidRuntime(973):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-15 11:37:05.890: E/AndroidRuntime(973):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-15 11:37:05.890: E/AndroidRuntime(973):  at     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
10-15 11:37:05.890: E/AndroidRuntime(973):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
10-15 11:37:05.890: E/AndroidRuntime(973):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please provide crash logs?

Comment: i have added the logcat

Comment: Can you post the `FragmentBuy` code and it's layout?

Answer (score 0):

Your view holder pattern implementation is worng .

Try this link.
http://www.codeofaninja.com/2013/09/android-viewholder-pattern-example.html

Applying view holder pattern will solve your problem and make the list scroll more smoothly . 
There are lags in your getView method, as you are finding the reference of textView for each row. These all can be overcome by view Holder pattern

Answer (score 0):

ohh i got it...
i was not using default id for listview in my layout(xml file)..
it  should be android:id="@+id/android:list",

thankyou everyone for your time and help...